# Why does list.insert() not leave gaps?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This might be silly question but imagine the following scenario: you are filling up a list of lists, which is to be converted to a `DataFrame` once it's fully populated. You don't know the final size in advance, thus it's not possible to pre-allocate in the right size.

While populating the rows (i.e. the nested lists) if you try to index the list beyond it's length it will give an `IndexError`, which is not unreasonable:

```
>>> row = list()
>>> row.append('a')
>>> row[3] = 'c'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

However if you use the `insert(index, element)` method I would have expected to have gaps in the list (at least to have the option to have gaps). After all, if I just wanted to add to the end, I would have used `append(element)` instead.

```
>>> row = list()
>>> row.append('a')
>>> row.insert(3,'c')
>>> row
['a', 'c']
```

As we can see above this is not the case. Why is this the case?

Is writing a custom wrapper function that iterates over the list the only possible way to get a gapped list e.g. `['a', None, 'c']` (or some other default value)?

Comment: `None` is just an object, not a null pointer; there are no 'gaps' in your expected output. Yes, you'll have to build a custom function to achieve that.

Comment: `l.insert(index, value)` is the same thing as `l[index:index] = [value]`, and slicing always works (producing an empty slice if need be), normalised to the length of the list if the indices are too large otherwise.

Comment: If you are going to be building a `DataFrame` using a dict of dicts for a sparse representation has a tailor-made constructor: `pd.DataFrame.from_dict`, which takes an `orient` parameter that defaults to `'columns'` but can be set to `index` if each sub-dict represents a row. This will fill in gaps with `NaN`.

Comment: For example, try this:`pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'A':{1:'a',2:'b'}, 'B':{1:'A',3:'C'}}, orient='index')` and look at the differene between that and `pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'A':{1:'a',2:'b'}, 'B':{1:'A',3:'C'}})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Python lists do not support gaps; they are not sparse. 'Inserting' past the end is the same as appending.

Note that `None` is not the same thing as a null pointer in other languages here, it is *just a singleton object* used where other languages often use a null pointer; it's still just another object otherwise.

If you need a sparse datastructure, the simplest way to do this is to use a dictionary:

```
row = {}
row[3] = 'c'
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably not through the functions in `list` directly. How about storing it in a `dict` and then create a list once fully populated?

```
d = {index: item for index, item in yourData}
result = [None]*max(d.keys())
for index, item in d.items():
    result[index] = item
#result is now a list with None filled at indices that do not have data..
```